# Override Symfony2 UplaodedFile

Tags: php, symfony

I try to upload a photo through a form.
I would like to override/extend \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class. 
I haven't found a solution from 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

is this possible to do so and if yes how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you need to add to the UploadedFile class?

Comment: Have you looked at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html? You probably want to create a Model/Entity which contains the actual file and additional info (like image dimensions or something...). If this does not work for you, please expand your question as to how you would like to alter UploadedFile.

Comment: What do you need to add to the UploadedFile class?

I want to add some more methods to save original file to a location and also apply watermark to images.